# How to sort or order by a comma separated value present in a column to descending order in HANA

Tags: sql, hana

I need to order by the column values in `HANA` which are separated by Comma in Desc order.
Here is the sample of actual data

```
SUBS_IDS
22,1
3,22,1
170,180
```

Now i want to sort this column in Desc order, like

```
SUBS_IDS
22,1
22,3,1
180,170
```

Can you please help me with this?

I have tried `STRING_AGG` function along with using an order by.
And i tried to do an Order by in the end, and results didn't come in my favour.

## Hana

```
select distinct dsx.subs_ids, dsx.document_name_id, dsx.document_name 
from ZTED_GLOBAL.Y_DOCUMENT_SUBSTANCE_XREFS dsx 
where dsx.document_type_id = 1
order by dsx.subs_ids
```

Comment: I think the logic you need to follow here is to break comma separated values into rows, sort them and then concatenate them again.

Comment: Hi Ankit, we tried that. But there are other fields which are dependent on these, like the names/descriptions of those numbers. Those values are getting hampered when we do this.